# pass props as a function doesn't work in a function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a 3rd party component where customComponent props receive a function, so I have this

```
<Form customComponent={() => <input type='text'/>}
```

but then I have condition so I decided to put my customComponent at function level

I did this in another way

```
renderCustomComponent = () => {
    //whatever logic goes here
    return () => < input type = 'text' / >
}
render() {
    return <Form customComponent = { this.renderCustomComponent } >
}
```

why I got nothing in Form? Aren't those 2 identical? something is wrong with second approach.

Comment: you're returning a function in the second aproach, return the input instead : `return <input type='text'/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think you should do this because if customComponent has validation
>   i.e it requires **function** then **@Giang Le** solution will not work

```
renderCustomComponent = () => {

    //whatever logic goes here
   return <input type = 'text' />
}
render() {
    return <Form customComponent = { this.renderCustomComponent } >
}
```

or

```
renderCustomComponent = (props) => {

    //whatever logic goes here
   return <input type = 'text' />
}
render() {
    return <Form customComponent = { (props)=> this.renderCustomComponent(props) } >
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot exe `renderCustomComponent` function. It should be

```
render(){
  return <Form customComponent={this.renderCustomComponent()}>}
}
```

and

```
renderCustomComponent = () => {
    //whatever logic goes here
    return <input type='text'/>
}
```

Comment: what if Form.propTypes={customComponent: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired};

Comment: Type of customComponent is Component not a func.

Comment: op said "**I'm using a 3rd party component where customComponent props receive a function**